# API End Point Which works on Basic Auth

Tags: spring, spring-boot, api, security

I am developing an API end point in Spring boot which will accept Basic Auth, and on the basis of user name and password I have to validate the requester, how can I achieve this in Spring boot ?

Answer (score 1):

Use `Spring Security` Framework.
The Framework has built-in support for Basic Auth.
This is the best way to go in Spring Boot.